# How to catch event firing from class constructor

Tags: c#, events, constructor

Here is an example...

```
public class CodeGenerator
{
     public delegate void GeneratorCalculatorEventHandler(decimal Fond);
     public event GeneratorCalculatorEventHandler eventName;

     public CodeGenerator()
     {
          eventName?.Invoke(0);
     }
}
```

How could I catch the event? If I do this:

```
CodeGenerator CodeGen = new CodeGenerator();
CodeGen.eventName     += CodeGen_eventName;
```

The event is fired when the handler is not subscribed to it yet. Is it possible to subscribe to an event on initialiazation?

Comment: i know i said that, how to to it right way .. thats what im asking

Comment: That doesn't seem possible, perhaps a workaround where you use an `Init()` method after the contructor?

Comment: Pass it in the constructor

Comment: Pass the handler to the constructor and do the constructor hook the event, that's the only way an event will be attached at that moment.

Comment: @ShadyOverflow I'm interested to know what you're trying to achive

Comment: You shouldn't be needing this...  The answers show that it is doable but that's just going further down the wrong path.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was thinking exactly that, why would you want an event fired when the class instantiates?

Comment: well, its kinda hard to explain, the current situation where i only need this is in the test application/simulator, in the release version im not using that event, which is fired in the constructor.... :// and its kinda secret code :D i dont like to expose it :D xDD (joking)  :))

Comment: Are you also going to invoke the event after the constructor has completed? If not, there's a better solution than the accepted answer

Comment: hmm not exactly, the given event is fired only once in the middle of the constructor code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the handler to the constructor and attach it to the event, something like:

```
public class CodeGenerator
{
    public delegate void GeneratorCalculatorEventHandler(decimal Fond);
    public event GeneratorCalculatorEventHandler eventName;

    public CodeGenerator(GeneratorCalculatorEventHandler listener)
    {
        eventName += listener;
        eventName?.Invoke(0);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        CodeGenerator gen = new CodeGenerator((sen) => { return; });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this works, anyway to be honest, i wish there was different, cleaner way, but still, as long as ti works, its all good, thank you sir. and everyone else who commented on the quesiton.

Answer (score 7):

As the comments said, this is a bad code smell. It sounds like you're doing something very unusual here and you should consider trying to find a different way to solve your problem.

One of the reasons it smells bad is: **if the calling code knows to pass the handler to the constructor, then that code already knows that the constructor is being invoked.** The caller could simply invoke the handler *itself* with the constructed instance! Events are typically for situations where something happens that the handler could not predict or control, like the user clicking a button.

I would not pass the handler to the constructor, were I in your situation. I would use a static event.